# extract caller phone number over pushbullet API

Tags: c#, push-notification, pushbullet

is there a possibility to extract just the caller phone number from the notification pop up generated by Pushbullet (in Windows)?

I want to develop a C# program that should be executed directly after someone calls and the user should be able to take notes of the call and save it in a DB.

Just in case it is not possible with pushbullet API, is anyone aware of the best solution for such use case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question directly, but if all you are using PushBullet for just texting you might try mySMS instead. It's less expensive and has a lot more going for it in regards to just texting. I had previously tried to make pushbullet work for a project and was forced out because of limitations.

Comment: thank you @DarrylHardin. I am much more interested in getting the callers number as a string to in my code.